# It's possible to use the draw_buffer extensions with THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to create a little project with THREE.js, but i need to use the draw_buffers extensions. I've been searching, and i found nothing. 
So I was wondering if there is a way to use directly the draw_buffers extension?

**EDIT**
The idea would be if i have a Fragment shader like:

```
#extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers : require
// varyings and uniforms

void main(){
     gl_FragData[0] = // some data here
     gl_FragData[1] = // some other data here
     // other rendertargets
}
```

Since every `gl_FragData` it's attached to a texture, how do i pass/convert those textures to a THREE.js texture?

Answer (score 1):

Well i finally found a workaround.

I first do this:

```
    texture = new THREE.Texture();
    texture.__webglTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture.__webglTexture );
    texture.__webglInit = false;
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, size, size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, null )
```

Then i can simply, bind the textures to the framebuffer:

```
   gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1.__webglTexture, 0);
   gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2.__webglTexture , 0);
   // Any other texture that i need
```

and then i can simply:

```
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,FBO[0]); 

    renderer.setSize(size,size);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);

    shaderSwap();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,null)
```

Then in the second pass i just need to have the textures as uniforms.